# Enabling /bus/refresh endpoint in Spring Cloud Config Client

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-bus

My Spring Cloud Config Client has dependency to `spring.cloud.starter.bus.amqp`, but it is still not enabling `/bus/refresh endpoint`

```
build.gradle    
compile("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit:1.1.3.RELEASE")    
compile("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bus-amqp:1.2.2.RELEASE")
```

I have these dependencies in my config client application, but still not enabling `/bus/refresh`, `/bus/env`.

Please let me know what am I missing in my client application.

**Note:**

```
spring.cloud.bus.refresh.enabled: true
spring.cloud.bus.env.enabled: true
endpoints.spring.cloud.bus.refresh.enabled: true
endpoints.spring.cloud.bus.env.enabled: true
```

I have tried setting up these indicators in `application.yml` or `application.properties` as these are used by `BusAutoConfiguration`, 
to enable `/bus/*` endpoints.

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(value = "endpoints.spring.cloud.bus.refresh.enabled", matchIfMissing = true)
```

In my Spring Cloud Config Server application I have disabled these endpoints, i.e., set to false

```
endpoints.spring.cloud.bus.refresh.enabled: false
endpoints.spring.cloud.bus.env.enabled: false
```

and observed that during Spring Boot startup `/bus/*` endpoints are not being enabled.

Comment: Are you importing the bom? What does 'not enabled' mean? you hit it and you get a 404, what?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you map client's url to `/bus/refresh`? I believe it's mapped to `/refresh` by default.

You could also try sending a POST request to client app at:

```
curl -X POST http://server:port/refresh
```

I also believe you might not need `spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit` dependency, just `spring-cloud-starter-bus-amqp`.

BTW I published a detailed post with working demo at: [Refreshable Configuration using Spring Cloud Config Server, Spring Cloud Bus, RabbitMQ and Git](http://tech.asimio.net/2017/02/02/Refreshable-Configuration-using-Spring-Cloud-Config-Server-Spring-Cloud-Bus-RabbitMQ-and-Git.html) that might help you as a starting point.

Comment: Thanks [http://stackoverflow.com/users/6679072/ootero], issue is resolved

Comment: @ootero what do you mean by to map client's url to  /actuator/bus-refresh

Comment: @legend
The application using Spring Cloud Config Client dependency. Also, I think I mentioned /actuator/refresh not /actuator/bus-refresh

Answer (score 5):

Updating this question with my findings as of 2018/04/12

/actuator/bus-refresh is the way to go from the config server.

In your application.properties:

```
spring.cloud.bus.enabled=true
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=bus-refresh
```

Example:
curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/actuator/bus-refresh

Signals all registered clients to update their configs.

Most of the existing articles I've found don't have this but I managed to find the simplest one based on trial and error and tidbits of solutions here.

Comment: According to David Syer of Spring Cloid, this shouldn’t be. It’s a bug that is going to be fixed sometime July so expect this to change .

Comment: I used the properties you mentioned above which helped me half the way. Along with that I also updated my maven dependencies in my micro-service module from **spring-rabbit** to **spring-cloud-starter-bus-amqp**. I have provided my answer/solution below just for the latest spring version & release. Thanks, Chad.

Comment: @Chad Did you get this error wile enabling the spring cloud bus ? - : No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.StreamBridge' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

Comment: This is a very old discussion and I have not been using Spring for a while now, so I wouldn't know.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the exact same issue. My observations are as follows:
I rectified that, the RabbitMQ/AMQP maven dependency as my primary issue.

My micro-service & springCloudConfigServer module are using the following: **2.2.4.RELEASE - Hoxton.SR1**

My pom.xml is as follows:

```
        <!-- Use this! I replaced this maven dep. for following one -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bus-amqp</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- I was using this maven dep. initially which when replaced by the above solved my issue. Avoid using this for now.
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-rabbit</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        -->
```

My application.properties / bootstrap.properties is as follows:

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=bus-refresh
```

This URL worked for me: **http://localhost:8080/actuator/bus-refresh**
and not:  */bus/refresh* OR */bus/env*

1) You need to have the **spring-boot-starter-actuator** and **spring-cloud-starter-bus-amqp** maven dependencies in both, micro-service module and your springCloudConfigServer module as well.

2) In my micro-service module,  when I used **spring-rabbit** maven dep. & when I tried executing the **URL: /actuator/bus-refresh** it always failed with error response 404! for some reason.

3) Then, I updated my micro-service pom file from *spring-rabbit* to **spring-cloud-starter-bus-amqp**, & tried the same URL again. It worked! My deductions were simple. 
It's just that 'spring-rabbit' didn't support **/actuator/bus-refresh** for some reason for sure. (I learned this after doing a trial & error for same)

Hope this helps you.
If it doesn't, you can refer [this link](http://www.appsdeveloperblog.com/spring-cloud-bus-refreshing-config-changes/) & [this also.](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-bus/2.1.x/single/spring-cloud-bus.html#_bus_endpoints)

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing code, it is found that `spring.cloud.config.bus.enabled` is set to false or overridden.

I was using enterprise framework jar on that top of Spring Boot; which was having `spring.cloud.config.bus.enabled` as true in `bootstrap.yml` and but this was overridden by config server property file i.e., git properties files repository was having false as value and for which preference was given.

```
localhost:<port>/env
```

shall display all properties from different sources; like config server, application.yml as part of service jar. Out of one which gets preference.

```
"configService:github uri": { list of properties }
"systemProperties": { list of properties }
"applicationConfig: [classpath:/application.properties]": { list of properties }
```

Below spring `env` rest resource is being used to ensure the exact value of this property.

```
localhost:<port>/env/spring.cloud.config.bus.enabled
```

Answer (score 0):

Mine is YAML,but writing you .properties representation.
after adding below options having an empty `POST` to config server port worked for me
http://ourserver:1234/actuator/refresh

```
management.enpoints.web.exposure.include: info, health, refresh, bush-refresh
spring.cloud.config.sever.bus.enabled: true
```